# Add Checkbox in AngularJS for search

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm developing a simple website with angular JS which will have various project details involved in my company. All the inputs are stored in project.json, so i'm accessing those values in the below html to display. `{{project.popup.location}}` data will have multiple location for example US,EU,ASIA. as of now i have developed this to display all projects data. Now I want to add a checkbox option for `{{project.popup.location}}`, so that i can see only the location which i have selected. Is that possible ? Any way to do this.

project.html

> {{project.popup.framework}}    {{project.popup.location}}
>       
>         
>           {{project.name}}
>           
>           
>             
>               Monitoring
>               Incidents Management
>               Problem Management
>             
>             
>               
>                 {{project.coverage.monitoring}}
>                 {{project.coverage.incident}}
>                 {{project.coverage.problem}}
>               
>             
>           
>           {{project.vertical}}
>           View
>   Details

Sorry for the very high level explanation, this is my first front end development I'm a JAVA developer. i have researched and spend a lot time to develop this. So please forgive me if it's too basic. If required i will add the controller and JSON files.

Comment: You're probably wanting to look at ngShow.

Comment: And just by the way you may want to look at using angular 2 with typescript it's still in beta but will have an official release soon and from what I've heard using the typescript compiler is easier to manage and has a structure that looks more like Java then normal JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

By my understanding of your question, what i understood was that you want to display the location selected from the check box.

> You will need **models** to work on what you want.
>
> The **ngModel** directive binds an input,select, textarea (or custom form control) to a property on the scope using NgModelController, which is created and exposed by this directive.

Here's a simple use-case to get you started.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <title>sample</title>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script> <!-- AngularJs 1.5.0 -->
 </head>
  <body ng-app>
    <div>
      {{ repoLimit }}
    </div>
    Set Limit: 
    <select ng-model="repoLimit">
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="100">100</option>
        <option value="1000">1000</option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps...

> References- https://angularjs.org/
>
> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel